# Eclipse extremely slow, continuously blocked in NonEssentialElementsFilter.hasFilteredChildren

Tags: java, eclipse, performance

I have a long-lasting problem with eclipse, quite blocking, that started after eclipse Luna (no problem with Luna). For example, this problem is occurring with the most recent version of eclipse, whatever performance options I change (advised by other answers from stackoverflow).

With my quite big project (thousands of classes), eclipse is very slow (stuck several minutes or tens of minutes) quite randomly, when I open it, but later when I open project tree nodes, when I refresh, update the SVN working copy, etc.

Using JVisualVM, I can see that all the time is spent in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.NonEssentialElementsFilter.hasFilteredChildren` and, in fact, in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.getElementName` and

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.concatWith...
```

I tried a lot of things (decorations, antivirus, breakpoints, recreating a new project, ...) but nothing helps.

And with Luna or previous versions, I did not have any problem like this. And I tried with a lot of newer versions, Mars, Neon JAVA only, Neon JEE, etc., they all have the same problem.

I hope someone can help, because it is quite blocking!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known problem (see [**Eclipse bug 506009**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506009)) which has not yet been fixed.

As a workaround use the *Package Explorer* instead of the *Project Explorer*.

**Update:** The Bug has been fixed in the meantime. **Upgrading to Oxygen.3** (released on March 21, 2018) should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank-you for this answer, but I just tried it, and this does not solve the problem. It even seems to be a lot worse with oxygen! I And I re-created a complete workspace / project from zero... Any other idea?

Comment: *all the time*, *a lot of things* and *worse* are very unspecific. Without information I can only recommend to use plain Eclipse and also a new workspace.

Comment: *"Disabling the Working sets, the issue disappears."* https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/155

Comment: This is exactly what I did : I installed eclipse from zero and created a completely new workspace, and the problem is occurring again. The unspecific terms concerned my previous tries, not for this time. I don't think this is unspecific. An I have no working set, so this is not related to the problem.

Comment: Freezes the UI, are you blocked when opening or editing a file? How often and how long does it take? Did you try disabling working sets? What was the result?

Comment: It is generally not linked to opening a file, but if I synchronize the project explorer with the current file, then it can happen, because opening folders in the project explorer may cause the problem. It generally happens when the project explorer needs to be refreshed : first opening, update from SVN repository, manual refresh, etc. But as we work as multiple SVN contributors, this happens very often, and the UI si generally blocked more than 5 minutes, up to 1 hour, especially with oxygen. Working sets are not enabled on my eclipse (at least from perspective settings, is there another way?)

Comment: What do you mean with *blocked*? Freezes the UI or is a modal dialog displayed? It sounds like an SVN team provider problem: Do you use *Subclipse* or *Subversive*?

Comment: Blocked means GUI freezed, with or without a dialog. I use subclipse, but this is not linked to it, because some problems occur without it (and the hot spots I see are never related to subclipse).

Comment: Finally, I removed project explorer and replaced it by package explorer, and it seems to be much better! I did not realize there were two explorers. I will tell you if this solves completely the issue for me, but the problem with project explorer will remain.

Comment: Please enable *Error Reporting* and *UI Responsiveness Monitoring* (*Window > Preferences: General > Error Reporting* and *... > UI Responsiveness Monitoring*) and send these automatically generated reports along with your observations (Package vs. Project Explorer) to Eclipse.

Comment: I did it, and it seems to be a known problem (that I had not found...) : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506009. Thank-you for helping.

Comment: Thx. I changed the answer and added a comment to the bug with your observation: http://eclip.se/506009#c19

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the workaround of using Package Explorer.
Another workaround if you are set on Project Explorer, is to disable the options that seem to be causing the contention. In Project Explorer "settings" (downward facing triangle to the right), go to Filters and Customization / Content. Then uncheck everything except Java Elements. That helped for me - but I eventually just switched to Package Explorer.